# What do you suggest to keep track of new published papers?

Tags: publications, software

I already know of the app Researcher, but lately I found it is quite buggy and was wondering what people do to keep updated. Do you just join mailing list from selected journals or search daily for some keywords? Or is there something else I could use?

Comment: For Pubmed listed research use a keyword alert via email?

Comment: You can create email alerts from Pubmed. You can tailor the email frequency and keywords, number of entries etc.

Answer (score 2):

Just follow all the people in your subfield on twitter. At this point that's easier than google or pubmed alerts, plus you can see when they're hiring too.

That + conferences (if conferences ever come back) is how I stay up to date.

Answer (score 2):

I have RSS feeds on Feedly for all the major journals in my field, and I scan the titles every few days. Fortunately it is not a huge field, so this isn't too difficult - I can imagine it would be an overwhelming amount of information in some fields.